# Access Raspberry Pi behind a NAT firewall through Internet

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iptables, raspberry-pi, iot

I have been developing projects with Raspberry Pi 4. For the current project I am running a NextCloudPi server on it. I am able to access the server using my Internal IP. I want to access it using a public domain name or in other words through open Internet. My ISP does not allow static IP and used CGNAT. Also I tried to port forward on my router's admin panel, but couldn't find the required setting.

I tried Zerotier, which creates a VPN and I can access the CloudServer through the static IP assigned under VPN but the transfer speeds are really slow. Another issue is that I need to install it on all the devices through which I am going to access the CloudServer and ofcourse on the RPi4 itself.

Is there any other option that you guys probably have to access RPi4(Basically IOT devices) through Internet? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

`ip addr` output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether dc:a6:32:6a:82:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 192.168.1.35/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0 valid_lft 85963sec preferred_lft 75163sec inet6 fe80::f6e0:36ba:532f:10e9/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000 link/ether dc:a6:32:6a:82:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: [Hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)). Or DDNS + port forwarding - we could help you find it if we knew the router model.

Comment: It's DBC EPON FTTH router with very bad admin dashboard. I am located in India and the router may not have a generalised Interface.

Comment: If it’s already accessible through a public up address then it’s already accessible through the open internet.  You are aware that a domain just makes it so you don’t have to use the IP address right? There are services that allow you to run an application, it publishes the up address to that service, and you access the machine through a domain.  It’s easier to use a static option address but dynamic dns do exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. I have used `ngork` to create virtual tunnel. I tried to use `ngork` earlier but was unable as I was running the service on *port 80*. When I ran the `nrogk` http service on *port 443*, I was able to access the NextCloud server using the domain name shown on the ssh terminal. NextCloud uses *port 80 for http* and *443 for https*. I am really not sure why I was not able to access the NextCloud on *port 80*. This may help if someone is stuck in the similar problem. The problem with `ngork` is, once the raspberry pi is restarted you will have to restart the `ngork` service as well and of course the domain address will also be changed. Though my use case don't have any problem with it.